# Не отображается рисунок в OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

Решил разобраться с координатами. Сначала делал без glOrtho было все нормально, потом добавил и эта пакость больше не работает. Буду благодарен если объясните как работают матрицы (`glMatrixMode()`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void changeSize(int w, int h) {
    // определяем окно просмотра
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    // используем матрицу проекции
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    // Reset матрицы
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(0.0f, w, h, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    // вернуться к модели
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void renderScene(void) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f(-1.5, -1.5);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 1.5);
    glVertex2f(1.5, -1.5);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // инициализация
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("Урок 2");

    // регистрация
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);

    // Новая функция изменения размеров окна
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);

    // основной цикл
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то все отображается, в левом верхнем углу, просто **очень** мелко

Либо установите

```c
glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, -1.5, 1.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

И тогда левому верхнему углу будут соответствовать координаты `(-2.0, 1.5)` а правому нижнему `(2.0, -1.5)`

Либо оставьте как есть, и левому верхнему углу будут соответствовать координаты `(0.0, 0.0)`, а правому нижнему `(w, h)`. Но тогда нужно изменить координаты вертексов соответствующим образом.

```c
glVertex2f(50.0, 400.0);
glVertex2f(200.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(350.0, 400.0);
```

В первом случае при изменении размера окна масштаб будет меняться, а во втором - нет.

Ну или можно сделать масштабируемый вариант с сохранением пропорций

```c
double ratio = (double)w / h;
glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.0, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: А почему мы делаем сохранение пропорций только для OX ?

Comment: По `y` масштаб фиксируем, по `x` подстраиваем под него. Если по двум осям сразу фиксировать, получится как раз без сохранения пропорций. А так квадрат всегда будет квадратом. А почему именно по `y` фиксируем - так и во всех играх делают. например потому, что мониторы бывают широкие и узкие, бывает и несколько мониторов соединенных горизонтально. Было бы жутко необычно если бы при этом обзор по `x` оставался бы фиксированным.

Comment: Точнее наоборот :) В общем при изменении ширины окна масштаб не меняется - только картинка шире становится.